# class with static and instance methods

Tags: javascript

The goal - create function, that behaves like class with static methods and at the same time can be used to create instanses. All this resides in dedicated namespace. I am looking for "standard" ptototype approach. And is it good practice in general?
I tried to avoid use reference to "class" by function name. If I would have 10 or more static methods it could be difficult. In first example I used _self, and in another method defineProperties.

```
var MyNamespace = (function() {
    
    function MyClass0(e) {
        this.e = e;
        var _self = MyClass0;
        
        _self.prototype = {
            instanceMethod: function() {
                
            }
        }
        _self.staticMethod = function() {
            
        }
        if (!e) {
            return _self;
        }
    }
    function MyClass1(e) {
        this.e = e;
        MyClass1.prototype = {
            instanceMethod: function() {
                
            }
        }
        var properties = {
                staticMethod: {
                    value: function() {
                }
            }
        };
        Object.defineProperties(MyClass1, properties)
        if (!e) {
            return MyClass1;
        }
    }

    return {
        MyClass0: MyClass0(), // use _self
        MyClass1: MyClass1() // use defineProperties
    }
})();
```

Comment: Good practice these days would probably to use a JS class. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I agree with Andy, this is all but good practice from my perspective. Why don't use use a simple ES6 classe in which you would get static method if you want to. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Comment: @Andy support for older browsers should be. The problem - create "flexible class" for static methods and for instances. I want to make code compact, easy to read and not separate logic, creating two parts or something.

Comment: The only browser that doesn't support `class` is IE (not Edge). You really can't, today, be trying to write code that IE doesn't support.

Comment: Don't replace your prototype. You lose `Function.prototype` stuff then. Instead, simply attach to it. To define static methods, simply use `FunctionName.staticMethod = function() { ... }`.

Comment: *And is it good practice in general?* No, not at all. You write the most modern syntax available and supported in your focus browsers, then, if you need to support older less capable browsers as well, you use Babel.

Comment: Don't overcomplicate/overengineer, not necessary, not good. The best programmers keep simple as possible.